# How can I read data from network drive using SSIS package?

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

Hope everyone is keeping well.

I have created one SSIS package which is reading data from a flat file available in my network drive and inserting it into Azure Managed Instance DB. It is working fine when running it from Visual studio. But after deploying it in Azure Data Factory it is not working, I am getting error "Path not correct".
So to fix this issue I created one storage account and in this storage account I created FileShare. I kept my file in storage and connected it with FlatFile source in SSIS, but here also I am getting same issue. It's working fine when running from VS but not working after deploying it in ADF.

My requirement is Read file and insert it into Database. SSIS package and database is in Azure.

Can someone please help here to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: You need to make sure that the account running the deployed solution can access the network drive. Usually Agent, but you can create a proxy account to run a package as well. Your account is running the package in Visual Studio.

Comment: The Azure-SSIS runtime in Data Factory needs a network connection to your drive. Does it have one? You would need to have express route or a VPN, then you would need to ensure that the VNET that your Azure-SSIS runtime is attached to can access on premises resources through this VPN or Express Route

Comment: More details here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/ssis-azure-files-file-shares

Comment: Nick I have tried that. It's working fine when running SSIS package from on-premise, but stopped working after deploying to ADF.

Comment: @VidyaVikasMishra When run package in ADF, it can not access the on-premise source.

Comment: @LeonYue Thanks for confirming but it's not reading data from Azure storage Fileshare as well. Can you please help